# Problema con expresión regular para patentes

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular `^[a-zA-Z]{3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{3,4}$` que funciona para patentes **aaa3333** o **aaa333**. Lo que necesito ahora que además de funcionar las patentes anteriores , funcione con **aa333a**.
Probé con la expresión regular `^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{3,4}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}$` que funciona con esas  patente pero además funciona con **aaa3333a**, **aaa333a**, **aa33a**, **aa333**, **aa3333**. Estas ultimas no tendría que poder funcionar.
Hay alguna manera de hacer que solo funcionen con **aaa3333**, **aaa333** o  **aa333a**.
Las expresiones las uso en JavaScript.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te faltó agregar los parentesis  ^[a-zA-Z]{3}[-]{0,1}([0-9]{3,4}[a-zA-Z]{1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Va a ser muy difícil combinar todas las opciones en una sola expresión sin agrupar. Encierra entre paréntesis los grupos a buscar y agrega un operador OR

- `(^[a-zA-Z]{3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{3,4}$)` - El primer grupo va a validar aaa3333 y aaa333
- `|` - Operador OR - Si no pasa la primera validación, continúa el análisis
- `(^[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1}$)` - El segundo grupo va a validar aa333a, pero no aaa333a, ni aaa3333a

```js
const tests = ['aaa3333', 'aaa333', 'aa333a', 'aaa3333a', 'aaa333a', 'aa333'];
const regEx = /(^[a-zA-Z]{3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{3,4}$)|(^[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1}$)/
tests.forEach(test => {
    // Probar cada caso
    console.log(test, regEx.test(test));
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Funciono correctamente.